# PHP jQuery value problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have problem to send value from php to jQuery script.

PHP looks like that:

```
echo "<a id='klik' value='".$row['id']."' onclick='help()' href='http://www.something.xx/tag/".$row['link']."'>".$row['name']."</a><br>";
```

and script jQuery:

```
function help(){    
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

var zmienna = j('#klik').val();
alert(zmienna);
j.post('licznik.php',{id:zmienna}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});

 }
```

licznik.php

```
    $p=$_POST;
    $id=$p['id'];
    echo $id;
    $wtf = "UPDATE tag_content SET wyswietlenia=wyswietlenia+1 WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($wtf);
```

And as I tested, it has problem at the begining (alert(zmienna); doesn't work, shows nothing). How to fix it? 
Thx for help and if u want more informations (like more code etc.) let me know.

Comment: the `<a>` tag is not an input field, use `attr(name)` like: `var zmienna = j('#klik').attr('value');`

Comment: not that it effects your question, but don't forget to add "return false;" to the help() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `a` tag can't have a value. What you can do is pass the id as a parameter:

```
echo '<a id="klik" onclick="help(\''.$row['id'].'\')">...</a>';
```

and in Javascript:

```
function help(zmienna) {
    alert(zmienna);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`{id:zmienna}` is not [JSON](http://www.json.org/), `{'id':'zmienna'}` is. Fix that.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the anchor tag has no value attribute (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html). Try this instead:

```
var zmienna = j('#klik').attr('value');
```

I would also advice against using `value`. If I need additional data, I use a tag like `data`.